# Shell Script to new file referring other files

Tags: shell

Can anyone please help in writing shell script for the below requirement.

I have a CSV file as shown below in comma separated format

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
```

There is another file in which the values are written as mentioned below:-

```
Ramesh
Suresh
```

With the help of above two files I need to construct new file.

```
<root>
<env name="A" domain="B">
    <component name="Ramesh">
        <machine name="C">Ramesh</machine>
    </component>
    <component name="Suresh">
        <machine name="C">Suresh</machine>
    </component>
</env>
<env name="D" domain="E">
    <component name="Ramesh">
        <machine name="F">Ramesh</machine>
    </component>
    <component name="Suresh">
        <machine name="F">Suresh</machine>
    </component>
</env>
</root>
```

Comment: Include what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "<root>" 
while read csvLine; do 
   echo $csvLine |    awk -F ',' '{print "<env name=\""$1 "\" domain=\"" $2"\">"}' 
   csvcol3=$(echo $csvLine |awk -F ',' '{print $3}')
      while read secondFileLine; do 
         echo -e '\t<component name="'$secondFileLine'">'
         echo -e '\t\t<machine name="'$csvcol3'">'$secondFileLine'</machine>'
         echo -e '\t</component>'
      done < SecondFile.txt
   echo '</env>'
done < file.CSV
echo "</root>"
```